# 127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times - Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel

I am writing a web application using Laravel, that features a dashboard as the main portal. To get here, you need to log in. You also need to be authorised at a certain power level, which in this case is anything above 15.

However, when I run the authentication check middleware, I get the error `127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times`. I don't see what the problem is here, considering there is only 1 redirect being run.

web.php:

```
Route::middleware(['logged.in', 'has.auth:15'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\Dashboard\Dashboard@index')->name('dashboard');
});
```

Here's the end of the middleware with the redirect:

```
if($auth->authlevel < $needed){
    return redirect()->route('index');
} 

return $next($request);
```

If anyone has any solution, please share. Thank you in advance!

Comment: bypass `index` route in your condition `if($auth->authlevel < $needed && !$request->routeIs('index')){`

Comment: @Girish Wouldn't it be better if he/she doesn't apply the middleware to the `index` route altogether?

Comment: @Girish unfortunately that did not work. Same error. Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: @Silidrone this is requirement specific.

Comment: @gowanjj `index` is a route name or  uri path?, the `routeIs` method will check only defined routes name

Comment: @Silidrone this middleware is imperative to the functionality of my application. I've tried applying it to just single routes and it's the same error.

Comment: @Girish index is a route name.

Comment: Ok, can you try instead of  `if($request->route()->getName() != 'index' && $auth->authlevel < $needed){`

Comment: @Girish same error.

Comment: What route is `index` ? Does it has any other middleware applied to it ? I think your middleware is working as expected but `index` is somehow redirecting back and back and back... You can also use `Log::info('SOMETHING')` before you do the redirect to `index` in your middleware so you can see if the middleware is redirecting and how many times.